# Run a process for at least 5 seconds in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, process, timer

My goal is to force a process to run for at least 5 seconds (any amount of time really).  I am working of the .NET Framework 3.5, with Service Pack 1.  The idea is that the document holds some information that the user must see, so to safe guard against them immediately clicking to close the document, we can force it to stay open for some time.  I developed a small test UI, consisting of a button, and then three radio buttons (one for each document).  Here is my code behind...

I define the strings for the file paths, the string for the chosen file's path, and int to store the process's ID, a boolean for if they can exit the program, and the thread and timer declarations such as..

```
string WordDocPath = @"Some file path\TestDoc_1.docx";
string PowerPointPath = @"Some file path\Test PowerPoint.pptx";
string TextFilePath = @"Some file path\TestText.txt";
string processPath;
int processID;
bool canExit = false;

System.Threading.Thread processThread;
System.Timers.Timer processTimer;
```

In the constructor, I initialize the thread and timer, setting the thread's start method to a method called TimerKeeper(), and then I start the thread.

```
processTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
processThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(timeKeeper));
processThread.Start();
```

I have the timer set to count to 5 seconds, upon which it will set the canExit boolean to true.

```
    public void timeKeeper()
    {
        processTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(processTimer_Elapsed);
        processTimer.AutoReset = false;
        processTimer.Interval = 5000;               //5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
    }

    void processTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        canExit = true;
    }
```

The rest is my button's click event, which deicides which file path to use to start the process, starts the timer, and then starts the process itself..

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)PowerPointRadioButton.IsChecked)
        {
            processPath = PowerPointPath;
        }

        if ((bool)WordDocRadioButton.IsChecked)
        {
            processPath = WordDocPath;
        }

        if ((bool)TextDocRadioButton.IsChecked)
        {
            processPath = TextFilePath;
        }

        try
        {
            canExit = false;
            processTimer.Start();

            while (!canExit)
            {
                processID = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processPath).Id;      
                System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(processID).WaitForExit();

                if (!canExit)
                {
                    processTimer.Stop();

                    MessageBox.Show("Document must remain open for at least 5 seconds.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

                    processTimer.Start();                   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error dealing with the process.\n" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

This actually works, for the most part.  The user still can close the document, but if it has not been 5 seconds, it will reopen.  Except for the word document (.docx).  Things go smoothly for the powerpoint and text files, but the word document has some strange behavior (please note that all 3 files are in the same file directory).  When I choose the word documents radio button and click the button, the word document opens, BUT I am also prompted with the message box from the catch block, alerting me that a "Object reference not set to an instance on an object" exception was thrown.  This only occurs for the word document.  Like I said, the word document still opens (I can see it's contents, just like the powerpoint or textfile).  The exception causes the lines that check to see if they can exit to be skipped, so the document can close immediately, which is a problem.

Can anyone see my issue here?  Or if there is a better way to doing all of this (I am a wpf/c# newbie)?  I just don't understand why this only occurs for the word document, and not the powerpoint and text files.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea. You cannot guarantee they'll read it and you might annoy them with this.

Comment: I'm with @MilkyWayJoe - this is a good way to make your users resent your software, and doesn't make them any more likely to read your text

Comment: Just a thought... Some softwares I install display the Licence Agreement during installation and it does not allow me to go through with the installation if I don't *read* the full licence. Although they cannot guarantee I've read it, they sorta force me to scroll down to the bottom of the document. You could do something similar to that (I don't know exactly how to accomplish that so that's all I can suggest at this time)

Comment: If you really need to do this, can't you create a form with the file contents in it, then prevent that form from closing for a period of time?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe and tomfumb - you're looking too far into it.  This isn't an actual application.  I am teaching myself C# and wpf and I just want to know why it fails for the Word document and not the others.  The my goal was to figure out how to force a process to stay running for X seconds, and I kind of got it to work. I am not developing actual software for someone, I'm actually still in school.  Besides, I would use Interop anyway for PowerPoint and Word.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - But towards your License Agreement idea, maybe a way to accomplish that would be to check if the vertical scroller was at its bottom?  And if so, enable the checkbox?  Not sure if that is correct or not, just an idea.

Comment: @Ryan That's kinda what I was saying. I don't know how to do that in MSWord from the running app, or even if it's possible. The way I see it you'd have to open the document's content *in* your app. That might lead to other obstacles tho (ppt). Overall, I find it great that you're putting effort to learn this kind of stuff, I'm just not sure if opening another app (like word) is the way to go, but since you're just doing it with the intent of learning, I see nothing wrong with researching and trying. Even if you don't find how to do *this*, you'll learn a lot of *can* and *can't do* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that the associated application is not the word application itself, but some intermediate application that launches word on your behalf.

To find out, keep a reference to the process object, and check if it has already terminated, what it's executable path is.

Having said that, why do you need this annoying behavior? You cant stop people from looking the other way. Is it supossed to fullfill some legal requirement or something?

Comment: No I am just trying to teach myself how to keep a process running for at least 5 seconds or something.  This isn't an application, I just wanted to know why the word doc has an error and powerpoint or the text file doesn't.  I should've chose different file extensions so anyone wouldn't get caught up on this being an actual legal thing for software.  Its just me teaching myself.  Anyway I'll choose you since you have a general idea of what could be wrong..

Answer (score 1):

If this is run on the user's desktop you are subject to the proper app being installed (e.g. Word) and how it is configured. If these are read only files on a share then I could convert them to XPS so you could show them in a DocumentViewer. And rather than force them to wait 5 seconds to click make them say yes to a dialog box that they have read and understand the document.  Or have this on a page with an "I agree" button as MilkyWayJoe suggested.